# Build NaturalSpec on Mono 3.0 on Mac

Tags: f#, mono, f#-3.0

Building NaturalSpec hits NUnit snags on Mono.  What's the way to make NUnit testing there pass?

https://github.com/forki/NaturalSpec

Comment: What is the exact snag - do tests fail or does Nunit itself not run?

Comment: If you post your question to [F# Open Source group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/fsharp-opensource), I'm sure Steffen (author of NaturalSpec) and others can give you some hints.

Comment: Downvote--this isn't very far from "It doesn't work"

Comment: downvoting too, paste the exception...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was that it could not find a file; it turned out to be the fsc.exe in NaturalSpec.fsproj.  I edited the project, namely FscToolPath, to point to the root of fsc, and exported FscToolExe in shell to be the right one, after which it did build.